# C# Obtener propiedades usando Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

En C#, Como puedo obtener las propiedades de un tipo de dato en especifico usando reflection? por ejemplo obtener solo los strings:

Se que asi se obtienen todas las propiedades:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

como se obtendrian las propiedades de tipo de dato string?

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta esta incompleta, deberías añadir más contenido o código, si tienes dudas consulta [ask]

Answer (score 0):

si ya logras todas las PropertyInfo[] devuelta por la funcion que mencionas, sólo te resta recorrer el array y consultar si PropertyInfo[i].GetType() == typeof(string)

```
// Obtiene las propiedades del objeto
PropertyInfo[] LasPropiedades = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

// Buscamos las que son de tipo string
for(int i=0; i < LasPropiedades.Length; i++)
{
     if(LasPropiedades[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
     {
            // Do something....
     }
}
```